# Graphics preview in Lyx gives `Error loading file into memory`

Tags: lyx

When I add a pdf figure into lyx the preview works only for the current session.
When I restart Lyx I get an error: `Error loading file into memory`. This only
seems to occur with .pdf files (i.e. not with .svg or .png) and has no effect on
the final rendered PDF document.

I've seen references to this bug in several places online but in those case the
issue was that previews were never generated. Also, I have pdf2ps and pdftoeps
installed so this shouldn't be the problem either.

Running Kubuntu 12.04; Lyx 2.04

Comment: Hard to tell what's going on without more info. You could try running LyX from the command line with `lyx -dbg graphics` and posting the output around when the error occurs. It could be a caching problem. You could also try using the Ubuntu PPA to get a development version of LyX to see if that fixes the problem: https://launchpad.net/~lyx-devel/+archive/daily

Comment: Well, running `lyx -dbg graphics` spewed tons of text which I couldn't redirect to a file using `lyx -dbg graphics > out`. Of the text left on the shell screen I couldn't find anything that would be the obvious piece of information.
I might try to get lyx straight from the PPA but I'm afraid of bugs.

Comment: There are *less* bugs in the PPA 2.0 package (which will be released as 2.0.5 shortly). The debug information is printed to standard error so you have to redirect with `lyx dbg graphics > out 2>&1`. That will redirect both standard out and standard error to the file `out`.

Comment: Adding:`deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/lyx-devel/daily/ubuntu quantal main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/lyx-devel/daily/ubuntu quantal main`
To my resource list didn't help (I'm not getting any new version from it). Also it turns out I have the latest version from the `ppa:lyx-devel/release` (the ubuntu repos have an older version of lyx).

Comment: As for exporting the debug output, again I can't see anything obvious. I have many lines: `../../../src/support/FileName.cpp(950): filetools(getFormatFromContents)
 Couldn't find a known format!`
but many other saying: `../../../src/support/FileName.cpp(945): Recognised Fileformat: pdf`

Comment: OK. Three separate ideas: (1) For the PPA, because the authors didn't want to overwrite your current LyX installation, the package is named differently. After you do a `sudo apt-get update` do `sudo apt-get install lyx2.0` (which will install what will become 2.0.5 soon) or `sudo apt-get install lyx2.1` (maybe less stable but maybe fixes your problem). (2) maybe try just Tools > Reconfigure. Sometimes that can solve things. (3) if nothing works, send a message to the mailing list: lyx-users@lists.lyx.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [scottkosty](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/12212/scottkosty) suggested in his comment, the bug is seemed to be solved in Lyx 2.05 and above which can be obtained directly from the daily build ppa (`ppa:lyx-devel/daily`) by installing packages `lyx2.0` or `lyx2.1`.